# python3: can't open file 'model_main_tf2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I've been tried to training model with tensorflow on google colab.
This is the script code i've been tried to run

```
!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config
```

but then i got this error:

```
python3: can't open file 'model_main_tf2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

anyone know what should i do?

Comment: do you have a file called model_main_tf2.py? is it in the same directory you run that command in?

Comment: actually file mode_main_tf2.py was in same folder as /model. Actually i write the dir path above !python blabla script, but it still error.

Comment: This is the error /content/gdrive/My Drive/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo 2020-11-16 23:52:09.967334: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1 Traceback (most recent call last): File "model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module> from object_detection import model_lib_v2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Answer (score 0):

Pls. Give the complete path to the model_main_tf2.py Or run from the directory which contains this file. It seems this file is not present in the directory from where you are running this command.

Comment: actually i've been add complete path to model_main_tf2.py above the script i write, but it still got error like there's no such directory

Comment: Error like this:/content/gdrive/My Drive/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo
2020-11-16 23:52:09.967334: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2031

Answer (score 0):

you need to compile you proto repo to create from .proto -> .py files with
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

you need to install protoc! it's programming language
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-to-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-solved/65379